# Data table error

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Im using a datatable to show records from a DB, using PHP.

See my code below;

```
<table class="table datatable-basic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Name</th>
      <th>Address </th>
      <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?
  $result9023=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hr_locations")or die('ERROR 315' );
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result9023);

  for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result9023); $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result9023);
    $location_id = $row ['id'];
    $name = $row ['location'];
    $address = $row ['address'];

    echo "         <tr>
        <td>$location_id</td>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$address</td>
        <td class='text-center'>Edit</td>
      </tr>
    "; } ?>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

The table is showing correctly, with the data populated as it should however I am getting the below error when the page loads.

[image: Error]

I have looked at https://datatables.net/tn/4 however it's not making much sense?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: *"DataTables has requested data for a given row, of the {parameter} provided and **there is no data there, or it is null or undefined**."*

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Aware of this, but looking for an answer to the above question first

Comment: Not sure what this means @JayBlanchard?

Comment: Which "above question"? The "making not sense" question? There is no other question in your question. You might be retrieving a row that isn't there. Try setting `$i = 0` in your for loop - most arrays begin counting at 0.

Comment: That was a response to the PDO part, sorry

Comment: @JayBlanchard - By setting `$i = 0` just adds a blank row? and the error still shows?

Comment: it is good you have shown the php, in this case, we now also must see the resulting html source from your browser.  we're guessing there is no data in the table due to some kind of error in logic or query.

Comment: @WEBjuju - Sorry what HTML source do you need to see?

Comment: how does the clientside dataTables initialisation look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most MySQL array start with 0 do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
```

Set `$i = 0` then state that `$i` must be less than the number of rows (if you have 4 you will get 0,1,2,3 (4 rows, properly indexed). Instead of counting the rows again, just use the variable you already set for the count.

---

You're actually probably doing a little too much with your code. Instead of using an unnecessary for loop, just use a while:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result9023)){ 
    $location_id = $row ['id'];
    $name = $row ['location'];
    $address = $row ['address'];

    echo "         <tr>
        <td>$location_id</td>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$address</td>
        <td class='text-center'>Edit</td>
      </tr>
    "; } ?>
```

This way you're making sure to catch each row returned from your query without possibly duplicating or skipping rows as you might do when using a for loop along with `mysql_fetch_array()` as you're trying to do.

Comment: What does `mysql_num_rows()` give you @user3092953?

Comment: Sorry, new to PHP, where would that go?

Comment: That gives 11??

Comment: Is there anyway we could continue in chat?

Comment: Not table to chat from this location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130020/discussion-between-user3092953-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: if i add another <tbody> to the code, I dont see the error, however I see 'there is no data in this table' on row one and then my data?

Comment: Can you `print_r($reresult9023);` right after you return the result and add the print out to your question?

Comment: Then do `var_dump($result9023);` right after the query